Why is the indexed_search extension not showing up?
I'm fairly new to TYPO3 and have tried to install the indexed search extension. I'm following these instructions.
So far I've done:

Installed the package via composer composer req typo3/cms-indexed-search

Created a page called Search

Included the TYPOSCRIPT in the constants.typoscript + setup.typoscript respectively


<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:indexed_search/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.typoscript">

<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:indexed_search/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript">


Added the General Plugin Type to the page

Unfortunately it doesn't show me the indexed Search in the General Plugin or anywhere else. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing anything?
Thanks a lot in advance!

I'm quite unsure, if <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT ...> is still working (at least it will cause many log entries): https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Feature-82812-NewSyntaxForImportingTypoScriptFiles.html

This didn't seem to be the issue here. It's a bigger project with a lot of these import statements. But I'll bring this up regardless, thanks for the input!

instead of using <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT ... you should prefer to include the static Typoscript in the root typoscript template record (or an extension template on the search page).

Depending on your TYPO3 version, it is necessary to activate a required package ('1. Activate "indexed_search" in the Extensions Manager.'). Since v12 TYPO3 will automatically activate packages in composer-mode. Before v12, requiring just copied them into the correct folder.

There was one more thing needed: Adding it to the Page.tsconfig.
I added the extension + pluginname to the list_type and now it shows up under General Plugin + in the frontend.
columns {
 1 {
     name = Content
     colPos = 11
     allowed {
               CType = list
               list_type = indexedsearch_pi2
             }
    }
}


So you have EXT:content_defender installed in your instance? (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_defender). This is important information - to help and also for others to understand the problem and the solution.

Yes, content_defender is installed.
